# Reading UINT 128 from Node JS Buffer

Tags: node.js, buffer, int128

I am programming a Node JS client that's querying a third-party server for information. Part of the message that I receive back from the third party server is a UINT 128 (specified in documentation). However, from what I can tell, NodeJS buffers do not support reading 128 bit ints from buffers. I have checked [this page](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) and the two most likely functions (reading BIGINTS and reading unspecified byte length ints) both don't support 128 bit integers.

I've already tried installing and using the [big-integer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer) module, but if that is the correct method, I couldn't understand how to read the bytes out of the buffer into a big-integer object.

How can I read a UINT128 out of a NodeJS buffer? I'm' willing to use bit arithmetic if necessary, I'm just not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

I did it by using getBigUint64 on a DataView twice, then calling toString on both, concatenating the strings and parsing that string as a BigInt... it's dumb but it seems to work. You may also be able to concat the 64bit BigInts using bitwise operators but I haven't tried.

```
readUInt128() {
    let a = this.readUInt64();
    let b = this.readUInt64();
    return BigInt(a.toString() + b.toString());
}

readUInt64() {
    let result = this.view.getBigUint64(this.pos, this.littleEndian)
    this.pos += 8
    return result
}
```